# How to find same entities in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I used the polyglot library for Named Entity Recognition and stored the result in a numpy array. Now the elements of these two numpy arrays do not match other.

```
REL_LIST = np.array(['ریس جمهور', 'تولد', 'استاد', 'کارمند', 'ریس'])
SENT_LIST = np.array(['رئیس جمهور محمد اشرف غنی تاکید ورزیده که حکومت افغانستان نباید در گفتگو های صلح در حاشیه رانده شود.'])
FINAL_NER_LIST =[]

for sent in range(len(SENT_LIST)):
    list = SENT_LIST[sent].entities
    FINAL_NER_LIST.append(list)
    for rel in range(len(REL_LIST)):
        if REL_LIST[rel] in SENT_LIST:
            FINAL_NER_LIST.extend(REL_LIST[rel])
```

My aim is to check if any entity of `REL_LIST` in `SENT_LIST` and the output of the polyglot NER is as below:

```
[[I-PER(['محمد', 'اشرف']) I-LOC(['افغانستان'])]
[I-LOC(['میونیخ', 'جرمنی']) I-PER(['عبدالعزیز'])]
[I-PER(['اشرف']) I-LOC(['کابل'])]
[I-PER(['اشرف', 'غنی']) I-LOC(['افغانستان'])]]
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome?
Also what is the difference between `SENT_LIST` and `REL_LIST`?

Comment: `SENT_LIST` is a list of all sentences from a file. `REL_LIST` is a list contains relations that I have extracted from `SENT_LIST` by implementing the `polyglot`. Now I want to check in each sentence if any element from `REL_LIST` is in `SENT_LIST`, should be inserted in `NER_LIST`, to show the relation between two entities, for example, `CEO(Bill Gate, Microsoft)`. In here `CEO` is in `REL_LIST` as it was appeared in first sentence of `SENT_LIST`, I want to added to the first element of `NER_LIST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I still do not understand the problem but maybe something like this will work?

```
NEW_LIST = []
for sentence in SENT_LIST:
    NEW_LIST.append([sentence.entities])
    for rel in REL_LIST:
        if rel in sentence:
            NEW_LIST[-1].append(rel)
```

`NEW_LIST` will be a list with the same length as `SENT_LIST`. Every entry will first contain the entities and then the relations.

Comment: `LEN_SENT = 0
word = 0
while word <= len(REL_LIST):
    if REL_LIST[word] in SENT_LIST[LEN_SENT][:]:
        k = np.insert(vector1[LEN_SENT], word, REL_LIST[word])
        print(k)
    LEN_SENT = LEN_SENT + 1
    word = word + 1
    if LEN_SENT == len(SENT_LIST) and word == LEN_SENT:
        break` This one only give one output. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: The code you shared is working, but not appending on specific entities. I mean one index is shared to all entities

Comment: I see the problem but if there are two Person Entities, how would the program know which one to assign the value from REL_LIST to? This information is not in the list

Comment: You are right, but for that, I will use TFIDF and weight vector to assign only on the most famous one. that is why for now I am working on just entity pairs. when it is complete I will go with machine learning. thank you